# UICollectionView not loading fully until I scroll

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view that I want to display hourly weather in. I seem to have a problem with loading the cell, and for some reason scrolling forwards and then back loads the cell fully. Before I scroll the collection view, all of the constraints do not work and one label doesn't show it's info.

[image: Before scrolling] 
Before scrolling

[image: After scrolling (this is how I want the cells to look like)] 
After scrolling (this is how I want the cells to look like)

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return newhourlyWeather.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! hourlyWeatherCell

    // Configure the cell

    let hWeather = newhourlyWeather[indexPath.row]

    if let HourlyTemp = hWeather.temperatureh {
        cell.temperatureHLabel.text = "\(HourlyTemp)º"
    }

    if let HourlyTime = hWeather.convertedTimeH {
        cell.timeHLabel.text = "\(HourlyTime)"
    }

    if let HourlyRain = hWeather.precipProbabilityh {
        cell.rainChanceHLabel.text = "\(HourlyRain)%"
    }

     cell.iconhView.image = hWeather.iconh

    return cell

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: to know what is the problem i might need some code

Comment: Without code and further information of the constraints, this question can't be answered.

Comment: updated question @vikingosegundo

Comment: reloading the collection view will populating the cells doesnt seem to be a good idea to me.

Comment: but hey: you are doing it after return, so it will be never executed.

Comment: I tried putting it before the `return cell` but the app crashes. @vikingosegundo

Comment: Didnt I tell you, that to was a bad idea?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you populate your cells asynchronously, if so then add a mycollectionview.reloadData() at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem by adding `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before the `return cell`.  Everything loaded as expected without any scrolling!

Comment: I think you had constraint issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` inside `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Also if you are using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and you are applying the `snapshot` inside the `viewWillAppear`, you need to add some delay to make it work correctly like this:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
    // apply here the snapshot
}
```