# UICollectionViewCells won't load unless scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and I populate it with cells.

I have a loading animation which stops to indicate all cells have been populated, but the cells won't show up until I scroll (Might take a few tries).

This is similar to this:

[UICollectionView not loading fully until I scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008170/uicollectionview-not-loading-fully-until-i-scroll)

But difference is that mine won't partially load - but won't at all.

My `UICollectionViewDataSource` :

```
extension ProductsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource
{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if searchActive
        {
            return filtered.count
        }
        else
        {
            return products.count    //return number of rows in section
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "product_collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductsCollectionViewCell
        cell.ProductImageView.image = nil
        cell.ProductName.text = nil
        cell.ProductPrice.text = nil
        cell.productUniqueID = nil

        let prodInCell =  searchActive ? filtered[indexPath.row] : products[indexPath.row]

        let prodID = prodInCell.getUniqueID()
        let dbRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(prodID).child("pic0.jpg")
        cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.ProductImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DefaultProductImage")
        dbRef.downloadURL(completion:
            {
                url, error in
                if let error = error
                {
                    print (error)
                }
                else if let url = url
                {
                    cell.ProductImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: url.absoluteString)
                    cell.ProductImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
        })
        cell.ProductImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //cell.ProductName = UILabel()
        cell.ProductName.text = prodInCell.getName()

        //cell.ProductPrice = UILabel()
        cell.ProductPrice.text = String(prodInCell.getPrice())
        cell.productUniqueID = prodInCell.getUniqueID()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Display selected Item
        prodToLoad = products[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "view_product_information", sender:self  )
    }

    // Swift 3.0
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat((collectionView.frame.size.width / 3) - 20), height: CGFloat(100))
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAt` , you have 2 asynchronous operations

1-

```
dbRef.downloadURL(completion:
```

2-

```
cell.ProductImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: url.absoluteString)
```

consider using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) as this will keep download the same image multiple times

//

Create an optional `urlStr` property inside the array item custom class/struct and set it when downloaded like

```
if let str = prodInCell.urlStr {

    cell.ProductImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:str), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
}
else {

       let dbRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(prodID).child("pic0.jpg")
       cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       cell.ProductImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DefaultProductImage")
       dbRef.downloadURL(completion:
        {
            url, error in
            if let error = error
            {
                print (error)
            }
            else if let url = url
            {
               prodInCell.urlStr = url.absoluteString // store for upcoming need
               cell.ProductImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url.absoluteString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))      
               cell.ProductImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
               cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    })

 }
```

//

also remember

```
import SDWebImage
```

and set any placeholder image inside project bundle to be loaded until real image is downloaded

Comment: I'll give it a shot :)

Mind taking a look here too ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268758/uicollectionviewcell-duplication?noredirect=1#comment91523045_52268758

Comment: I downloaded SDWebImage. What is the proper use for it here ?

Comment: It says "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

in "if let str = prodInCell.getUrlStr() "

Comment: declare the var like this **var urlStr:String?** inside the custom class that you fill the array from

Comment: I changed it to String? and changed the getter to getUrlStr() -> String?

And it still gives some error :/

Comment: I just changed the urlStr to public to make this easier for checking

Comment: And yup, it loaded great now :) What about this placeholder.png ? I should now add one ? Isn't it just my default picture for products ?

Comment: yes , it's a default image to be displayed , you can pass nil if you don't want to

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I also updated my other question

Comment: Hey, @Sh_Khan, a question - is there a method in SDWebImage to load a URL and in case it fails to STAY with the placeholder and not crash ?

Comment: this is the default of it